# Can't create file because file doesn't exist

Tags: java, file, ioexception

Java won't let me createNewFile because the file I want to create doesn't exist, which, *duh*, that's why I want to create it. Here's my code snippet.

```
System.out.println("Please input the path of the install directory.");

System.out.print(">");
installLocation = input.nextLine();

File spreadsheet = new File (installLocation + "diatracker.csv");
File settingsFile = new File (installLocation + "settings.txt");


if ( spreadsheet.exists() )
{
    if ( isValidFile ( spreadsheet.toString() ) )
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        spreadsheet.delete();
        spreadsheet.createNewFile();
    }
}
else
{
    spreadsheet.createNewFile();
}
```

And here is my error.

**Please input the path of the install directory.**

*C:\Users\DigiDuncan\Desktop\DiaTracker\*

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at DiaTrackApp.firstTimeSetup(DiaTrackApp.java:201)
    at DiaTrackApp.main(DiaTrackApp.java:50)
```

Please help me out, this program is really important to me. Thanks!

### EDIT: PROOF THE PATH EXISTS

[image: Proof the file path exists.]

### EDIT AGAIN: I'M DUMB

I literally just named the folder wrong, didn't I. Sorry for wasting your time, guys. **.~.**

Comment: Do you think this path is correct `C:\Users\DigiDuncan\Desktop\DiaTracker\` ?

Comment: Since JAVA is platform independent, try with a correct path syntax: file:///C://Users//DigiDuncan//Desktop//DiaTracker// . You should also not need createNewFile, since new File(path) already creates the file, when the path is correct. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: @mondjunge That is a URL, not a correct path syntax, and `new File(...)` does *not* create a file in the filesystem. There is nothing in your link that supports your claims.

Comment: @Harshit I do believe that yes, that path is correct. There is definitely a folder on my desktop called DiaTracker, which is why I'm confused by the whole situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most probably caused because the given parent folder path does not exist. A simple way of fixing this would be to use:

```
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

`File#mkdirs()` will essentially create all parent folders to the file if they do not exist, and also consider the given file as a new folder. This is why you should use `getParentFile().mkdirs();` if you want to still create a new file with the last part of the path being well, a file!

Edit: Just an extra note, the good side of using `getParentFile()` is so you do not have to worry about the file path being changed or incorrect at runtime.

You should also use `input.nextLine().replace("/", File.separator).replace("\\", File.separator);` in case the user input does not follow the OS's path guidelines.

Comment: Please see the dited post; the file path does in fact already exist.

Comment: I was dumb. But most people, including myself in the future, will most likely find this answer very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be able to create the file iff the parent directory exists...

To be sure:

```
// use `\\` or `/` or File.separator to be sure
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\DigiDuncan\\Desktop\\DiaTracker");
file.mkdirs();// to create parent folders
```

Now it should work.

It can't create the file if there is no folder... You can check:

```
file.exists();// also for folders
file.getParent().exists();// If parent exists, it should be able to create a child (if right permissions)
```

Comment: Please see the dited post; the file path does in fact already exist.

Comment: Then you should get new File("C:\\Users\\DigiDuncan\\Desktop\\DiaTracker").exists() -> true. It looks like there might be a space between Dia and Tracker... But I can't be sure. Besides, your image stops at `Track` not `Tracker`